# Javascript regex to match string but only show text

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an HTML element with a title inside, like this. `<details>Name of page</details>`

How can I make a regex to search for the `<details>` element, but only returning the text inside, `Name of page`?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit... do you have the HTML in a string, or is it part of the DOM?

Comment: @Felix - The HTML is a part of the string. Im filtering through the content, and returning the commented out content (`<!-- -->`) by using `return this.nodeType == 8;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thy this regex:

```
/<details>(.*?)<\/details>/
```

`$1` regex variable will contain the name.

Comment: This matches the string, but dosent remove the `<details>` tags. Is it just easiest to string replace it?

Comment: @cnotethegr8: Just let go. Regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: Use something like this in javascript: `myStr.replace(/<details>(.*?)<\/details>/,"$1")`

Answer (score 4):

You should never use regex to parse HTML. *Especially* not when the environment you use provides a DOM parser at your fingertips. Just use it:

```
var docpart = document.createElement("div"),
    details, text = '';

docpart.innerHTML = "your <details>&hellip;HTML string&hellip;</details> here";

details = docpart.getElementsByTagName("details");

if (details.length > 0) {
  text = details[0].textContent;
}

alert(text);  // "…HTML string…"
```

---

Since you mentioned jQuery in your comment, things get simpler. Here is the jQuery equivalent of the above:

```
var inputHTML = "your <details>&hellip;HTML string&hellip;</details> here";
var details = $("<div>", {html: inputHTML}).find("details").text();
```

Comment: I dont think this will work with the way im retrieving the string. I made a comment to @Felix Kling about it.

Comment: @cnotethegr8: What makes you think that? It does not matter if the string came from a comment, just try it.

Comment: Im very new to Javascript, I tried to get the element with jQuery like this, `jQuery('details').text();` and I was unsuccessful. I just assumed any method to go about this would have several lines of code, so i figured regex would be the best.

Comment: @cnotethegr8: Regex is not the best, for several reasons. Firstly it is generally incapable of reliably parsing structured languages like HTML (except for very, very narrow cases) and the more corner cases you try to cover, the more complex it gets, up to the point of unmaintainability. Secondly it does not understand HTML escape sequences (like the `&hellip;` mentioned above), whereas doing it in the DOM transparently deals with them. See my changed answer.